# How do you configure the mime_content_type() function to work correctly in php5?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php.ini, mime-type

I have a ubuntu 9.04 desktop that i'm using for my development machine with apache2 installed.

What are the steps that I need to go through to ensure that the mime types for files are determined correctly?

Currently all files are resolving to a mime-type of 'text/plain' because php is not configured correctly for [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at php.net it appears mime_content_type() is deprecated and it is now recommended to use Fileinfo. Check this thread for installation instructions on Ubuntu. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=722373

Comment: Why it is deprecated in favor of an inferior method I have no idea, thanks for the answer though.